# Submitted date of apex jobs

Tags: jobs, asyncapexjob

How to access Submitted date of apex jobs because it is not a standard field of asyncapexjob ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily access this info using SOQL. There is an object called **AsyncApexJob** that contains information about Apex jobs. It will hold several types of jobs (like unit tests, scheduled jobs, etc.).
It has a **CreatedDate** timestamp which you can use to find out when your job was submitted.

```
select  ApexClass.name, CreatedDate, JobType, LastProcessed, MethodName, ParentJobId, Status 
from    AsyncApexJob
where   ApexClassId in
    (select id 
     from   ApexClass)
```